# How to pass parameterized statements with values and table names to Psycopg2?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm basically trying to accomplish what the answerer pointed out here: [psycopg2 cursor.execute() with SQL query parameter causes syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354392/psycopg2-cursor-execute-with-sql-query-parameter-causes-syntax-error)

My statement is:

```
    cursor.execute('SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = %s' % (pkey,table,field, "%s"), (value))
```

But when I run it I get the error:

```
---> 89         cur.execute('SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = %s' % (pkey,table,field, "%s"), (value))
     90         res=cur.fetchone()
     91         if res==None:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Be very careful when doing this - make sure that 'pkey', 'table' and 'field' contain only a valid SQL identifier if there's any chance they've come directly or indirectly from user input. You're bypassing any SQL injection protection you get from using parameterised statements by doing this so you need to be very paranoid. For PostgreSQL I'd recommend "double quoting" each value in the SQL and checking the values to make sure they do not contain any double quotes or \ escapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem was **not** in quoting but in Python's tuple syntax.

As you already commented above, the correct way to represent *one*-element tuple is `(value,)`. In general the tuple syntax is (informally):

```
()
(value,)
(value, value)
(value, value, value)
```

and so on for multi-element tuples.

The accepted answer is not really correct and the change suggested therein is purely a matter of taste (having the last '%s' be appended after substitution vs. your attempt).

---

Keep this in mind: when doing common string substitution in Python, when you have a string with just one `%s`, you can drop the tuple and simply pass the single substitution string itself:

```
'foo %s' % 'bar'
```

This will result in `foo bar`.

You could try the same with `psycopg`'s `cursor.execute`, *maybe* it works (I would test it myself before posting, but I can't).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following, db module should take care of the proper quoting:

```
sql = 'SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s' % (pkey, table, field) + ' = %s'
cursor.execute(sql, (value, ))
```

Comment: if i add a "," after value in cursor.execute it works. so cursor.execute(sql, (value,))