# replacing variable in SQL statement using django

Tags: django, psql

I have a problem when using raw sql query which has a variable table name like

```
cursor.execute("SELECT description FROM %s WHERE id = 1", [table_name])
```

`%s` replaces the string in double quote which isn't executing properly.When I execute the above statement I get

> "NameError: name 'nike_tshirts' is not defined"

Comment: You wouldn't get that error from that code. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: (Pdb) cursor.execute("SELECT description FROM %s WHERE id = 1", [table_name])   
*** ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'nike_tshirts'"
LINE 1: SELECT description FROM 'nike_tshirts' WHERE id = 1

Comment: Is the table nike_tshirts all lower case in Postgres?

Comment: yes, it is. When I replace %s with nike_tshirts, the statement works perfectly fine, but when I sent it this way it doesn't.

Comment: That's clearly a different error; why did you post the original one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524482/psycopg2-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting found the answer, thanks SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Your should just put the table name between quotes `'table_name'` / `"table_name"` or define the variable before: `table_name = 'nike_tshirts'`.

So:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT description FROM %s WHERE id = 1", 'nike_tshirts')
```

or

```
table_name = 'nike_tshirts'
cursor.execute("SELECT description FROM %s WHERE id = 1", table_name)
```

should work just fine.

Python raises a NameError because it thinks you are referring to a variable, when you are trying to refer to a string.

Comment: It isn't working. Python replaces the variable as it is with single quotes, like- cursor.execute("SELECT description FROM 'nike_tshirts' WHERE id = 1") . Is there a way I could pass my table_name parameter without the single_quote?