# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "E'

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Everytime I try to use cursor.execute from psycopg2, he insert 'E' before each query parameters.

For exemple, when i try this :

```
with psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbName, user=BDD_USER) as conn, conn.cursor() as curs:
    conn.autocommit = True
    curs.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS %s', [extensionName])
```

I get this :
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "E'postgres_fdw'"
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS E'postgres_fdw'

I am forced to create my query before with sql.Identifiers to make it work.
If anyone has an idea of what I can do to solve this problem...

Comment: Try to pass the parameter using a tuple instead of an array, like this

Comment: What value does `extensionName` have? What does `type(extensionName)` return?

Comment: *I am forced to create my query before with sql.Identifier to make it work,* and this is a proper solution. `extensionName` is a Postgres identifier, you cannot pass it to `execute()` just like a string. Compare the first examples here: [SQL string composition.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql)

Comment: I tried with a tuple but same error

Comment: extensionName is a string

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsIS function to indicate psycopg2 to not convert the parameter as a string.

[psycopg2 TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524482/psycopg2-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting#answer-21539685)

```py
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

curs.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS %s', [AsIs(extensionName)])
```

Comment: You were right @Chris.. I found a better solution and edited my answer

Comment: It work that way, thnks !

Comment: No.  The correct way to do this is using the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module and `sql.Identifier`.

Comment: The problem with identifier is that it suround parameters with quotation marks

Comment: @Antonin. It creates it with double quotes which is correct for an identifier: `sql_qry = sql.SQL('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS {}').format(sql.Identifier('test_ext'))'`, which results in `cur.mogrify(sql_qry.as_string(con)) b'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "test_ext"'`. See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).