# Avoiding type errors in Python SQL statements passing integer as parameter in psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

Using psycopg2 library encounter this specific error when I pass the argument invite_id as an integer

```
def check_invitations(self, invite_id=2):
    try:
        cur = self.db_cursor
        cur.execute("""
            select id from invitations where deleted_at is null and accepted_at is null and rejected_at is null and id = %s
        """, invite_id) 
        return cur.fetchall()       
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in check_invitations: %s' % e)
```

```
Error in check_invitations: 'int' object does not support indexing
```

But when I convert invite_id to a string, the command executes and returns the fetchall():

```
def check_invitations(self, invite_id=2):
    try:
        invite_id = str(invite_id)
        cur = self.db_cursor
        cur.execute("""
            select id from invitations where deleted_at is null and accepted_at is null and rejected_at is null and id = %s
        """, invite_id) 
        return cur.fetchall()       
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in check_invitations: %s' % e)
```

To get the command to execute with the invite_id as an integer, I have to pass the int value inside a tuple with one value:

```
def check_invitations(self, invite_id=2):
    try:
        cur = self.db_cursor
        cur.execute("""
            select id from invitations where deleted_at is null and accepted_at is null and rejected_at is null and id = %s
        """, (invite_id,))
        return cur.fetchall()       
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in check_invitations: %s' % e)
```

My question, specifically, is why do I have to pass the integer inside a tuple, while the string can just be passed directly? I can make note of it and just do it, but I am attempting to understand why? What about an "'int' object doe not support indexing" is causing this situation (not really an issue).

Comment: What is the data type of var1, var2, var3, what are some example values? The code is not really complete but I would guess you can make the first variant work either by casting the variables to strings, like `(str(var1), str(var2), str(var3))` or by using different substitution variables, like `%d` instead of `%s` if the variable is an integer.

Comment: "does this solution leave me susceptible to sql injections" - yes it does.  Can you be more specific about the problem you have with the first method, which ordinarily prevents SQL injections?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - this is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524482/psycopg2-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting

Comment: What are the types of your vars? It would help if you provided a [mre].

Comment: @snakecharmerb - ok...thought I had fixed my issue with above script. Let me reproduce my exact error. Will get back soon!

Comment: @snakecharmerb - so...I can't recreate the type error issue I was having. So I am going back building the execute command per the psycopg2 docs. Think I should I pull this question down? Or rebuild all my execute commands first and see if the issue is encountered again?

Comment: We can close the question now as "not reproducible", if the issue comes back later then you can edit this question to provide more details, then it can be reopened.

Comment: @Marijn, read this [psycopg2 passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), there is only `%s`. `psycopg2` does Python --> Postgres type adaption automatically as shown here [Type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you for the links. Think passing parameters in psycopg2 can be frustrating. At least my experience and the and some of the comments in other questions, especially this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524482/psycopg2-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting

That question is closed but still don't think there is a real clear answer regarding passing parametes in psycopg2 library specifically.

Comment: I am not sure how much clearer the information at the link I posted could be.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - ouch! I am going to study it closely!

Comment: 1) What is the exact error message? **Add as update to question**. 2) This `(invite_id)` is not a tuple,  it is just a single object of whatever type the variable is. A `tuple` with  a single element has to have a trailing comma.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I have updated my question with a specific example. If you have a chance, please take a look!

Comment: A string supports indexing, for example `"abc"[0]` is `'a'`. Are you sure the results are ok in the string case, also when the `invite_id` consists of two or more digits? In any case, probably for both the string case and the integer case `(invite_id,)` would be the correct usage.

Comment: `execute` expects to receive a _sequence_ of values, with the length of the sequence being equal to the number of parameters that the SQL statement expects.  A string is a sequence, so a string of length one works in this specific case.  An integer is not a sequence, so it must be wrapped in a tuple or list (or other sequence type) to prevent the `TypeError`.  Using stand-alone strings as the values argument is quite brittle - for example it breaks for two digit integers - so it's considered better practice to wrap all the values in a tuple (or list, but passing a tuple is  conventional).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @snakecharmerb, @Marijn, and @AdrianKlaver - really the more robust solution here is to always pass the parameter as an item inside a tuple. For instance, passing the string directly only works if the length of the string == 1. If the string is longer, the execute won't work because now the sequence of the string is greater than 1. For instance:

```
def check_invitations(self, invite_id=22):
    try:
        invite_id = str(invite_id)
        cur = self.db_cursor
        cur.execute("""
            select id from invitations where deleted_at is null and accepted_at is null and rejected_at is null and id = %s
        """, invite_id)
        return cur.fetchall()       
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in check_invitations: %s' % e)
```

Returns this exception:

```
Error in check_invitations: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The better solution here is to pass all parameters inside a tuple.

```
def check_invitations(self, invite_id=22):
    try:
        invite_id = str(invite_id)
        cur = self.db_cursor
        cur.execute("""
            select id from invitations where deleted_at is null and accepted_at is null and rejected_at is null and id = %s
        """, (invite_id,))
        return cur.fetchall()       
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in check_invitations: %s' % e)
```

Tuples with one item requires a trailing comma to identify the variable as a tuple.